# Remove consecutive characters of certain type with RegExp in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for removing specific consecutive characters.

For example. I can use

```
var filtered = oldString.replace(/[^[\w]\s]|(.)(?=\1)/gi, "");
```

If I need to get rid of any consecutive characters.

And I can use.

```
var filtered = oldString.replace(/[^[\w]\s]|(,|;|\s)(?=\1)/gi, "");
```

If I need to get rid of consecutive commas, semi-colons and space characters.

But what I exactly need is to make string like `;,` look like `;`.

And string like `,,,,,  ;` look like single comma `,`.

So I need to get rid of any consecutive chars of some type.

How I am supposed to do that?

Comment: What about using `[,;\s]` instead of `\1`?

Comment: Try `.replace(/(\W)\W*/g, '$1')`

Comment: If you have a specific problem, please share an input string and expected output. Right now, the question sounds rather generic, hence my answer might not be that helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to match chunks of the characters that are matched with the same pattern but keep the first matched char only. Use

```
.replace(/(\W)\W*/g, '$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/83D3WB/1)

The pattern will  match:

- `(\W)` - a non-word char (and capture into Group 1 so that the `$1` backreference in the replacement pattern could restore this char)
- `\W*` - 0+ non-word chars (they will be removed from the string)

Note that this is a generic approach, and in most cases the pattern should be further adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, my understanding is that you want to replace a set of predefined characters occurring consecutively with the first occurring one. You can do this:

```
([;,])[;,]*(?:[;,\h]*[;,]+)?
```

- Matches any of `,`, `;` and horizontal spaces `\h` i.e single space or tab
- Matches only spaces that occur in between
- Using capturing group to capture first match i.e `([;,])`
- `(?:[;,\h]*[;,]+)?` is a non-capturing group which allows spaces in between

Replace with `$1`

This will replace a combination of `,`, `;` and spaces `\h` with the first one i.e

- `,,,,,,,,;` will get changed to `,`
- `;;;;;   , , , , ;, ;, ;`  will get changed to `;`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8i9nVA/1/)